# Authorize an Org issue

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, developer-org

Once I click on "Authorize an org" and then inserted name. The default browser opens. Org is authorized but still it displays continuous authorization till i cancel it. User-added imageAnd after cancellation it shows error exit code 1 . Gys please help, from past four days I am stuck and trying to resolve this issue . Tried almost everything killing node, reinstall vscode, changed default browser, verified path and project properly, what else can i do please help.
[image]
Help is appreciated. Thank you
[image]

Comment: Run `sfdx update` and try this again (_restart your PC after sfdx update, if needed_).

Comment: I am actually experiencing the same issue. Its not VS Code Extension (https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/2487#issuecomment-705907313) related rather its a bug directly in the CLI (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/650) if you can comment on that issue that will help